# Combining two different voltages into one regulated voltage at higher amperage

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, rectifier, amperage

The Commodore 64 user port has a +5V supply at 100mA and a 9VAC supply also at 100mA.  I need about 150mA from the port at 3.3 volts.

Is there a way I can use both supplies to get the amperage I need?

Can I rectify the 9VAC to DC and regulate it down to 3.3V, then regulate the 5V down as well with a second regulator and connect the two regulators in parallel?  Does that work like it might with battery cells?

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need both supplies.  9V at 100mA is 0.9 watts.  You need 3.3V at 150mA or .495 watts.  A switching supply that converts the 9V to 3.3V will certainly be efficient enough to give you the 150mA that you need.

Look at the TPS62130 from TI for example:

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps62132.pdf

There are countless other options from TI, Linear Tech, ON Semi, Maxim, Intersil, etc.

Comment: Is there a reference circuit for a supply like this?  A quick google produces large, overkill modules.

Comment: Sure, a more appropriate part might be this one: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps62125.pdf which has a reference design here: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slvu659a/slvu659a.pdf  You could just get the evaluation board from TI to test it out.

Comment: There is an even simpler, cheaper and easier solution, saving you from getting all the required components and soldering them on a board: buy a ready-made module from eBay such as this one: http://www.ebay.nl/itm/DC-DC-Buck-Converter-Step-Down-Module-LM2596-Power-Supply-Output-1-23V-30V-/171195478619?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_77&hash=item27dc0bb25b

You can trim it to provide you the required 3.3 V from the 5V DC that you already have. From the 9V is also possible but since that's AC you would also need a rectifier bridge and a capacitor.

Comment: You can't use the 5V, there's only 0.5W available.  Given conversion efficiency you won't get .495W out.  If the 9V is really AC you will need a bridge rectifier (you could use 4 Schottkys) and a filter cap, maybe 100uF.